# How to reorder a DENSE_RANK column considering multiple columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query following which have a DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER columns:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
    A.SL_NO, 
    A.ACC_NO, 
    A.ACC_NAME
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.ACC_NO, A.ACC_NAME) DRN,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ACC_NO, A.ACC_NAME ORDER BY A.SL_NO) RN
    FROM TEST_TBL A 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE A
ORDER BY A.SL_NO;
```

The query results in:

```
SL_NO   ACC_NO  ACC_NAME DRN RN
1        234      UNIP    3   1
2        234      UNIP    3   2
3        234      UNIP    3   3
4        256      PURP    4   1
5        256      PURP    4   2
6        289      KFAR    5   1
7        210      FHAS    2   1
8        210      FHAS    2   2
9        210      FHAS    2   3
10       110      PURP    1   1
11       110      PURP    1   2
12       110      PURP    1   3
13       110      PURP    1   4
```

But do wanna order the DRN column like this (The rank must be according to the acc_no and acc_name columns):

```
SL_NO   ACC_NO  ACC_NAME DRN RN
1        234      UNIP    1   1
2        234      UNIP    1   2
3        234      UNIP    1   3
4        256      PURP    2   1
5        256      PURP    2   2
6        289      KFAR    3   1
7        210      FHAS    4   1
8        210      FHAS    4   2
9        210      FHAS    4   3
10       110      PURP    5   1
11       110      PURP    5   2
12       110      PURP    5   3
13       110      PURP    5   4
```

Need suggestions to achieve it with or without using DENSE_RANK. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you just want the `DRN` column to be a dense rank as ordered by the `SL_NO` column.  We can subquery once, and arbitrary take the minimum `SL_NO` value per each account, and then use dense rank afterwards:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SL_NO, 
        ACC_NO, 
        ACC_NAME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACC_NO, ACC_NAME ORDER BY SL_NO) RN,
        MIN(SL_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY ACC_NO, ACC_NAME) AS SL_NO_MIN
    FROM TEST_TBL A
)

SELECT
    SL_NO, 
    ACC_NO, 
    ACC_NAME,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SL_NO_MIN) AS DRN,
    RN
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    SL_NO;
```

[image: screen capture of above SQL query]

### Demo

Comment: It works! Thanks...Didn't know that aggregate functions also works with over and partition...

Comment: Remember: Windows functions always run _last_ in a query (well...maybe except for `ORDER BY`).  So, if you have a `GROUP BY` query and use a window function, the window function will evaluate _after_ `GROUP BY`, and you may only refer to aggregates inside it.